# Determine the Gramian matrix in terms of the standard basis $B^3_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

> In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we have the basis
>   $B=\left\{\vec{b_1};\vec{b_2};\vec{b_3}\right\}$ with
>   $\vec{b_1}=\begin{pmatrix} 2\\  2\\  3 \end{pmatrix}, \vec{b_2}=
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  1 \end{pmatrix}, \vec{b_3}=\begin{pmatrix}
> 2\\  1\\  1 \end{pmatrix}$ and in terms of this basis, we have a
>   scalar product by the Gramian matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & 2\\  1
> & 3 & 2\\  2 & 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$. Determine the Gramian matrix in
>   terms of the standard basis $B^3_0$.

I'm not sure how to do this and I couldn't find much information about Gramian matrix on the internet either. So first of, by standard basis $B^3_0$ it's probably meant that you use Gaussian elimination, and that we use the basis together with the unit matrix, so then $B^3_0$ must be simply the basis in form of a matrix, 
$B^3_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2\\ 
2 & 1 & 1\\ 
3 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

The gramian matrix is defined as a set of vectors in an inner product space, so I guess in this case these vectors are the columns of $A$.

And now to get the gramian matrix of $A$, do I just need to multply $A$ with its transpose? On the other hand, this shouldn't be the correct solution because it must be in terms of $B^3_0$ and we woulddn't have made any use of it..? : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given an $n$-dimensional linear space $V$ endowed with inner product $(\alpha, \beta)$, suppose the Gramian matrices of $(\alpha, \beta)$ under two different bases $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n\}$ are $G_1$ and $G_2$, and 
$$(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n) = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)P \tag{1}$$
for some non-singular matrix $P$, then $G_2 = P'G_1P$. This result can be restated as that the Gramian matrices for an inner product under two different bases are *congruent* to each other.

In your case, take $\beta_i = b_i, \alpha_i = e_i, i = 1, 2, 3.$ It is easily seen that the transition matrix (as $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) = I_{(3)}$, the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.)
$$P = B = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

In addition, $G_2 = A$, therefore by $(1)$ the Gramian matrix under $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\}$ is given by 
$$G_1 = (P')^{-1}AP^{-1}.$$

It should not be difficult to calculate the inversion of $P$ and the matrix multiplication from here.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have just one question, what is the matrix $P'$?

Comment: The transpose of $P$.